# calculate age from textbox dob

Tags: excel, vba

"i have userform containing two textboxes TextBox1 belong to date of birth and textbox2 belong to age.How create code when enter date of birth in TextBox1 then show complete age and month in TextBox2 ?"

```
Dim Age
Dim Birthday As Date
Birthday = CDate(TextBox1.Text)
Age = Year(Date) - Year(Birthday)
TextBox2.Value = Age
```

i expect output e.g. 25.10 but actual output 25

Comment: Why do you expect 25.10?  Subtracting two whole numbers (the year values) will always return a whole number

Comment: 25.10 means age 25 years 10 month.  if any another code plz explain me

Comment: Then you need to take account of Months when you calculate Age.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DateDiff function provides the difference between the two dates in many formats . Using the Date Diff function we can get the number of months between the dates and convert them into the required format like below

```
Dim Age
Dim Birthday As Date
Dim years As Integer
Dim months As Integer
Birthday = CDate(TextBox1.Text)
Age = DateDiff("m", (Birthday) , (Date) )
years = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(Age / 12, 0)
months = Age Mod 12
```

Comment: ```                                                                                                                         
Private Sub TextDOB_AfterUpdate()
Dim Age
Dim Birthday As Date
Dim years As Integer
Dim months As Integer
Birthday = CDate(TextDOB.Text)
Age = DateDiff("m", (Date), (Birthday))
years = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(Age / 12, 0)
months = Age Mod 12
Textage.Value = years & "." & months                                                                            ```  textage value are negative like -25.-10

Comment: the arguments might have to be interchanged in the datediff function . Updated my answer above @Yogesh